# Hockey Cocoa pod integration error - Resource not found

Tags: cocoapods, hockeyapp

Yesterday my Xcode projects started failing with the following message:

error: Resource "$RESOURCE_PATH" not found. Run 'pod install' to update the copy resources script.
where "$RESOURCE_PATH" pointed to the hockey app pod.

I've tried:

- pod install
- completely removing cocoa pods integration and
  re-integrating it with my projects
- uninstalled cocoa pods from my
  system and reinstalled

Nothing works.  Has anyone had this issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: This issue is now fixed in the latest CocoaPods version [1.0.0beta.6](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.0.0.beta.6).*

---

This is an issue with the latest CocoaPods prerelease version `1.0.0beta.5`. It's being tracked [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4963) and a [Pull Request with a fix](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/5028) has already been opened.
In the meantime, you can switch back to using the current stable version of CocoaPods, `0.39.0` or use the Podspec `HockeySDK-Source` instead.